# How does Tensorflow evaluate bits of program that don't involve Tensors?

Tags: tensorflow

How does Tensorflow evaluate code that does not depend on Tensors inside of a graph?

If we have something like:

```
graph = tf.Graph() 

with graph.as_default():
    x = tf.constant([[1],[2]])
    print("hi1")
    y = tf.constant([[1],[1]])
    print("hi2")
    z = tf.add(x,y) 
    print("hi3")

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess: 
    z_output = sess.run([z])
```

How can I make sure that the `print()` statements are executed only if a certain Tensor like `z` is being evaluated? Right now it seems that all of them are executed as soon as the program is run.

Comment: You could add tf summaries, which log the progress of variables within the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow **does not** execute code that's outside the graph (like those `print()` statements); instead this is executed in the normal order by the Python interpreter. Another way of putting it is: **TensorFlow only evaluates bits of program that do involve tensors**. The `print()` statements will execute while you're constructing the graph, but since they don't add any nodes to the graph, they won't execute again when you actually run the graph (using a `tf.Session()`.

This might make sense if we look at what your example program is doing in more detail:

```
graph = tf.Graph()  # Create a new graph to contain a TensorFlow program.

with graph.as_default():  # By default, all created nodes will be added to `graph`.
  x = tf.constant([[1],[2]])  # Add a constant node to `graph`.
  print("hi1")                # Print a message *during graph construction*.
  y = tf.constant([[1],[1]])  # Add a constant node to `graph`.
  print("hi2")                # Print a message *during graph construction*.
  z = tf.add(x,y)             # Add an addition node to `graph`.
  print("hi3")                # Print a message *during graph construction*.

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:  # Create a session for running `graph`.
  z_output = sess.run([z])  # Run the node `z` and all nodes it depends on.
```

If you want TensorFlow to run some piece of code, you must add it to the graph. For this reason, TensorFlow provides mechanisms that replicate common language features, such as [`tf.Print()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#Print), [`tf.while_loop()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#while_loop), etc.